# How to match every second space with regex?

Tags: php, regex

I have the following sentence:

```php
$title1 = "Lorem Ipsum simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry Lorem has been the industry "
```

The result should look like this:

```php
(
  [0] => "Lorem Ipsum"
  [1] => "simply dummy"
  [2] => "text of"
  [3] => "the printing"
  [4] => "and typesetting"
  [5] => "industry Lorem"
  [6] => "has been"
  [7] => "the industry"
  
)
```

I tried `preg_split("/ /", $title1)` but that does not work like I expected.

Comment: To the OP: Where is the second `Ipsum` in your expected result?

Comment: How to match second space with regex ?

Comment: I'm afraid repeating your question does not count as a clarification. Please edit the question so as to address my query: You have two `Ipsum`s in your original text; one is at index `0`, but where is the other?

Comment: Instead of splitting on every 2nd space, you could just match `\w+ \w+`

Comment: _"I tried `preg_split("/ /", $title1)` but that does not work like I expected."_ - that's concerning. That you expected it to do anything else but that which it will quite _obviously_ do, I mean.

Comment: @CBroe You don't have to split hairs, do you? I made up the second part of that sentence so as not to leave the post as terrible as it was before I edited it; sorry if it doesn't sound natural enough.

Answer (score 1):

To split on the second space, you can split on the following pattern and remove the empty entries:

```
\S+ \S+\K
```

The pattern matches:

- `\S+ \S+` Match 1 or more non whitespace characters with a single space in between
- `\K`  For get what is matched so far, and then match a single space

For example:

```
$title1 = "Lorem Ipsum simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry Lorem has been the industry ";
$parts = preg_split("/\S+ \S+\K /", $title1, -1, PREG_SPLIT_NO_EMPTY);

print_r($parts);
```

Output

```
Array
(
    [0] => Lorem Ipsum
    [1] => simply dummy
    [2] => text of
    [3] => the printing
    [4] => and typesetting
    [5] => industry Lorem
    [6] => has been
    [7] => the industry
)
```

See a [PHP demo](https://3v4l.org/Ieo0n)

To split on the second set of 1 or more consecutive horizontal whitespace characters using `\h+` :

```
\S+\h+\S+\K\h+
```

See a [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/pAxIPT/1)

Comment: Good answer! To avoid more than one space as a typo, I would use `\S+\s\S+\K ` instead of `\S+ \S+\K `.

Comment: @ArvindKumarAvinash Thanks, yes that is why I added `\h+` to match horizontal whitespace chars (as `\s` can also match a newline) :-)